# Numerical analysis - integral - speed and length

Tags: numerical-methods, education, numerical-linear-algebra, stochastic-integrals, numerical-optimization

A race car completes a lap lap in 84 seconds. The speed of the vehicle is measured every 6 seconds from the start of the race, and is given in the following table in meters / second:

(the time is the first line, the speed is the second line)

[image: the time is the first line, the speed is the second line]

How I calculate  the length of the route? (Use the fact that distance is the integral of speed by time).

Comment: I was not instructed which method to use. We studied the middle method, the Simpson method and the trapezoidal method

Comment: Maybe it is possible to separate into 14 trapezoidal areas?
If it's a straight line then it's a trapezoid. Assuming the motion is equal in acceleration between any two measurements, I do not think anything can be said about the copy. It can go back and forth between any two measurements, stop and so on

Comment: any help? any good explain?

Comment: oh I didn't notice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By using the standard trapezoidal rule $S=\sum_{i=1}^{14}(t_{i+1}-t_i)\frac{v_{i+1}+v_i}{2}=3v_1+6\sum_{i=2}^{14}v_i+3v_{15}$. Different integration rules would give slightly different answers. By the way, the nonzero speed at the start is weird.